# Help with try/catch and accessing elements within the try

Tags: java, try-catch

```
try {
    inFile = new Scanner(file);
}
catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println("FileNotFoundException");
}
```

I have this code. However, after the try/catch statement I have the following:

```
while(inFile.hasNext()) {
}
```

The compiler is telling me that I have not initialized inFile. Do I need to put all of my code within the try/catch? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Well, what happens if an exception does occur? Will `inFile` be assigned anything (useable)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initialize inFile:

```
Scanner inFile = null;
```

**Edit:**

As others have mentioned, you should be careful that you could potentially get a NullPointerException in your while loop.  You should consider moving your while loop into the try block as well:

```
Scanner inFile = null;
...
try {
    inFile = new Scanner(file);
    while(inFile.hasNext()) {
    }    
}
catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println("FileNotFoundException");
}
```

Comment: And get a `NullPointerException`

Comment: True enough, but a that should be handled in the catch statement since an Exception is the only way that inFile should be null.  Alternatively, the while statement could be moved into the try block as Tomasz Nurkiewicz suggested.  We have limited context on where this fits into the OP's overall program.

Comment: Typically you shouldn't catch NPEs since it's a RuntimeException.

Comment: @yock - sorry, I probably wasn't clear.  I didn't mean catch the NPE.  I meant handle the FileNotFound in the catch (assuming System.out.println is just a temporary placeholder for actual exception handling) so that you either throw a different exception or return from the method or otherwise alter the execution path to avoid an NPE.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but since the while() loop comes after the try block it will still run following a non-RuntimeException, generating a NPE as a result of inFile being set to null. It seems to make more sense to avoid the NPE situation completely by designing away from using null.

Comment: As I said, if you consider the error fatal and throw another exception from the catch(FileNotFoundException) this is not an issue.  If you simply return from the method within the catch() this is not an issue.  If OP expects the file to be missing sometimes and wants to try other approaches to get his Scanner, or wants to instantiate it with some specific String so that it never leaves that block null it could be okay as well.  I'm assuming, based on the empty while loop, that this is not the final finished product.

Answer (score 2):

If you are getting a compiler error, you probably need to initialize `inFile` to null.

Note that later in your code you shouldn't assume that inFile is not null, you should always check it:

e.g.

```
if (inFile != null) {
    while (inFile.hasNext()) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: If he does that, he will get `NPE` when `FNFE` is thrown - probably not what was intended...

Comment: @Tomasz: Will he also get FOOBAR when he can't read your TLAs?  Please type out your words.  It really doesn't save that much time if you're a fast typist, and helps out new people (like the person asking this question).

Comment: @Merlyn Morgan-Graham: your right, sorry. I assumed `NullPointerException` and `FileNotFoundException` are so common, that the abbreviations would be clear. Unfortunately I can't edit my own comments...

Answer (score 2):

The compiler is complaining because if `new Scanner()` throws `FileNotFoundException`, `inFile` won't be initialized (BTW very unfortunate variable name). Your loop should be inside `try` block, which will also increase readability.

```
try {
    Scanner inFile = new Scanner(file);
    while(inFile.hasNext()) {
        //...
    }
    inFile.close();
}
catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println("FileNotFoundException");
}
```

Comment: +1 for the first complete (code sample) and correct answer.  Also, now that I see your `file.Close()` call, it occurs to me that he might want to stuff it in a `using` block :)

Comment: Probably want a `try`-`finally` in there. The catch could be put around the constructor, but there'd need to be some sensible control flow rather than a printf carry on.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you do. If an exception is raised the runtime will print "FileNotFoundException" and will keep running, although inFile will not have been initialized.

You should make the program return when stumbling upon this exception, or else do your operations on `infile` only when you are sure that it has been initialized correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The try block is not in the same scope as your while loop. Put the while loop inside the try block.

Comment: it is initialized in the try, presumably defined outside it.

Comment: That doesn't matter. It can be declared any number of places. Initialization is what's important and moving the while loop inside the try block puts it in the same scope as the initialization. That makes the declaration outside the try block unnecessary, but that's a simple refactor.

Answer (score 0):

No your code is fine, however local variables must be intialized so you have to set `Scanner inFile = null;`

And it is correct what you already have done, because if you move the local variable inside the try/catch statement you will not have access to it because of the scope.

```
Scanner inFile = null;

try {
    inFile = new Scanner(file);
    //more code
} catch (Exception e) {
    //exception code
}

while (inFile.nextLine()) {
    //loop code
}
```

If you had an instance variable it would have been automatically set to null, but in this case you have a local variable and then objects need to be initialized before you use it.

Comment: The loop should be inside the try because if an exception is thrown it shouldn't execute.  Or at least there should be a check for null before the while.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the warning is that you should set the Scanner to null initially.  However you should also move the while loop inside the try block, because if the exception is thrown you don't want that while loop to execute (because inFile will be null).

Answer (score -1):

Yes, as others have said, initialize inFile to null

However, you will also need to check that inFile actually points a valid file and is not NULL when you get to your loop 
e.g.

```
while(inFile!=null && inFile.hasNext()) {
}
```

Otherwise, you perhaps want to place the whole try-catch in a different loop to make the user select another file? Or just exit the program if the file is invalid? The missing element to the question is how you wish to handle invalid files. Does the program exit or re-prompt the user?